# nginx docker build fails

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I was using the following dockerfile to build a nginx docker image with some additional modules:

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add nginx-extras libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam
```

This was successful in the past. But when I try to rebuild the image now I get this error:

```
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:mainline-alpine                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:mainline-alpine                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN apk update                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN apk add nginx-extras libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam                                                                                                                                           0.7s
------
 > [3/3] RUN apk add nginx-extras libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam:
#0 0.632 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#0 0.633   libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam (no such package):
#0 0.680     required by: world[libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam]
#0 0.680   libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext (no such package):
#0 0.680     required by: world[libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext]
#0 0.680   nginx-extras (no such package):
#0 0.680     required by: world[nginx-extras]
```

I can't find any hint what has changed.
Is there another proper way to create a nginx docker container with additional modules installed?

Comment: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nginx-mod*&branch=edge&repo=&arch=x86_64&maintainer=

Comment: The 3 package names don't exist for alpine 3.17, with the package links you can find the correct names

Answer (score 0):

Try using Debian-based image?

```
FROM nginx:stable-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  nginx-extras  libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam
```

Answer (score 0):

In alpine `libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext` calls `nginx-mod-http-dav-ext` ([link](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/nginx-mod-http-dav-ext)), but I can't find the same package for `libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam`. You can build or build it from [sources](https://github.com/sto/ngx_http_auth_pam_module).

Alternative to it: use debian based images instead of alpine. Something like this:

```
FROM nginx:mainline
RUN apt clean && apt -y update && apt -y install --no-install-recommends nginx-extras && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```